# Django simple ModelForm not showing on page (I'm using class based-views), what could be the problem?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, modelform

I'm trying to build a form to use it as a filter for my project search page, but the {{form}} shows nothing. Here is how everything is set up:

**The model I'm trying to use from models.py**

```
class Exemplar(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Exemplares'
    tipoDeExemplar = models.ForeignKey(TipoDeExemplar, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Tipo De Exemplar")
    numeroDeRegistro = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Número Do Registro")
    especie = models.ForeignKey(Especie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    dataDoRegistro = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Data Do Registro")
    estadoDoExemplar = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="Estado do Exemplar")
    tipoDeMaterial = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="Tipo De Material")
    procedencia = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="Procedência")
    remetente = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="Remetente")
    armario = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="Armário")
    gaveta = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="Gaveta")
    complemento = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255, verbose_name="Complemento")
    amostraDeOrigem = models.CharFie
    fotoDoExemplar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='imagens/', verbose_name="Foto Do Exemplar")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.numeroDeRegistro
```

**My forms.py file (very short)**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from acervo.models import Exemplar

class ExemplarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Exemplar
        fields = '__all__'
```

**My view on views.py (seems to be working since I can open the page)**

```
class BuscaView(ListView):
    model = Exemplar
    template_name = 'busca.html'
    form_class = ExemplarForm
```

**Piece of the HTML template where I try to use the Django ModelForm**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

From what I've researched in other post and on YouTube tutorials, everything seems to be ok, but **only the button** shows up.
What could be the problem?

Comment: [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView) does not handles form by default but you can pass the form by overriding [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data)

Answer (score 0):

I think at first you need write `{% block content %}` in the line 1 or 2 of your code and in the end you should close it with `{% endblock %}` in the down of your code

And you should write your url view in the action in  tag;
`<form action="{% url 'app_name:url_name' %}">`

url_name:

```
`urlpatterns = [
    path('url', your_view, name='url_name'),
]`
```